# Current User inside my remote event receiver will always be app@sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, provider-hosted-app, remote-event-receiver

I am working on a remote event receiver which uses app only permission. now i am trying to get the current user who execute the RER:-

```
context.Load(context.Web);
context.Load(context.Web.CurrentUser);
context.ExecuteQuery();
var o = context.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName;
listItem["Author"] = context.Web.EnsureUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
```

but the `context.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName` will return `app@sharepoint` instead of the actual username, and the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` will return `object reference not set to an instance...`.. any advice on this please?
Thanks

Comment: The answer depends on which type of event you are handling.  Item Event, List Event, App Event?

Comment: @willman item event (item updated and item added)

Answer (score 0):

When you are handling an Item-triggered event, then the Properties parameter passed into your `ProcessEvent` or `ProcessOneWayEvent` methods has a `ListEventProperties` property which will contain the [CurrentUserId](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.remoteapp.spremoteitemeventproperties.currentuserid?view=sharepoint-server#Microsoft_SharePoint_RemoteApp_SPRemoteItemEventProperties_CurrentUserId), [UserDisplayName](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.remoteapp.spremoteitemeventproperties.userdisplayname?view=sharepoint-server#Microsoft_SharePoint_RemoteApp_SPRemoteItemEventProperties_UserDisplayName), and [UserLoginName](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.remoteapp.spremoteitemeventproperties.userloginname?view=sharepoint-server#Microsoft_SharePoint_RemoteApp_SPRemoteItemEventProperties_UserLoginName) that should all hold information about the user who "triggered" the event.